# Can I create secondary index on a table that already has data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to create secondary index on two columns for a table as we are facing huge nimber of look ups. I am trying to optimize the performance and thinking of a secondary index option. The table has already huge amount of data. Can I create secondary index on the table without creating the table again and creating a secondary copy.

Comment: It should be possible. May take some time...

Comment: Of course.  You use `create index` command and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Not only that, if you need to continue accessing the table while the index builds, you can use `create index concurrently`. See [the docs for create index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html).